# the intent always return the default value

Tags: android, android-intent

i have many activities and i need to move an integer data from one to another one >> 
in the first activity i have this code

```
 final Intent go_to_main = new Intent(getBaseContext() , MainActivity.class);
    go_to_main.putExtra("data" , i1) ;
```

and the secound one
 `Intent intent = getIntent() ;
        data = intent.getIntExtra("data",3) ;`

bbut always return the default which is 3 here 
i have tried the bundle but when i use it like that my app stoping when i click the button to move to the secound activity

```
 Intent go_to_main = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class);
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putInt("data", i1);
            go_to_main.putExtras(mBundle);
```

and in the secound one i have this code

```
Intent intent = getIntent() ;
data =     intent.getExtras().getInt("data") ;
```

the error in the logcat is :

```
2020-05-30 18:27:56.461 14976-15008/com.e.pluspath E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you have to use bundle.
for go_to_main intent:

```
Intent go_to_main = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class);
go_to_main.putExtra("data", i1);
```

And for your receiving end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent() ;
data = intent.getIntExtra("data", 0);
```

Comment: still return the default value

Comment: Try using PendingIntent for go_to_main intent. I had the similar issue, but solve with pending intent. 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext, i1, go_to_main, 0)

Comment: can u explain how to do it what  should i write in the second activity

Comment: It should be same in the second activity but in first activity I have setup like:
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn, pendingIntent);